# Clear user notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Notifications belong_to users and users have_many notifications.

On user's show (users_controller.rb) action I retrieve the user's notifications by:

```
def show
  ...
  @notifications = current_user.notifications if current_user
end
```

Notifications are shown properly but then I want to the user to be able to delete his/her notifications. I placed this in the UsersHelper.rb:

```
  def clearNotifications(notifs)
    destroynotifs = notifs.destroy
  end
```

My view (users/show.html.erb) which doesn't make sense is:

```
<div id="clearnotifications">
   <% clearNotifications(@notifications) %>
   clear notifications
</div>
```

There are three issues I am concerned about:

1. Is this a good practise?
2. How do I call this function from the text on the view? (link_to?)
3. Shouldn't i call users.save or notifications.save?

Thanks in advance for any tips/guidance. If you need any more info let me know and I will add it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a controller `notifications_controller` now in `routes.rb get "notifications/clear"`
create clear action in notifications controller

```
def clear
  current_user.notifications.delete_all
  render nothing: true# or whatever you want to render
end
```

now in view

```
<%= link_to "delete", notifications_clear_path, remote: true %>
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that. btw, I do have a notifications controller as I create notifications; before deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a controller action (`users_controller#delete_notifications` or `notification_controller#delete_all` or something else) that does deletion of notifications.

You can then, for example, call that action from javascript.

The key point here is: this imaginary html-ruby bridge does not exist.

```
<div id="clearnotifications">
   <% clearNotifications(@notifications) %>
   clear notifications
</div>
```

You can't call server-side code in this manner. To delete notifications, you have to send a request (by clicking a link to reload page or sending async request with javascript).

See docs on jQuery.ajax, for example.

Comment: About the view, thats why I mentioned: "My view (users/show.html.erb) which doesn't make sense"